# Bundling Python with pyinstaller --onefile --add-data not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used `pyinstaller --add-data "icon.png;." --add-data "casino.png;." debug2.py`which works fine but when I make a single file using `pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "icon.png;." --add-data "casino.png;." debug2.py` the executable no longer works.

I believe this is an issue with relative paths maybe?

Here is my python code for loading these assets:

```
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
image_path="casino.png",
```

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: What OS are you using? I've had problems with pyinstaller with Mac

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Are you able to create a onefile that works without the images? Is the problem with the image loading, or the `pyinstaller --onefile` functionality?

Comment: The file is successfully created but when I try and run it it closes with some issue about icon.png

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: The problem is the application closes I don't have time to read it can I force it to stay open?

Comment: If you run the executable from command line, the error might be displayed in command line

Comment: I tried that but as the exe opens a new terminal it does not work.

Comment: Well without an error message it's hard to know. Maybe a module that you use with the images isn't be bundled properly? Maybe it's paths like you said in the original question?

Comment: I think it was the fact that --onefile uses a temp directory and the python code is not set up to use it

Comment: Yep that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was fine on the pyinstaller end but when using --onefile the assets are unpacked in a temporary file so the python code was looking in the wrong directory.

To fix it I had to add

```
try:
   wd = sys._MEIPASS
except AttributeError:
   wd = os.getcwd()

icon_path = os.path.join(wd,"icon.png")

casino_path = os.path.join(wd,"casino.png")
```

Then change my paths for icon & casino to:

```
icon = pygame.image.load(icon_path)
image_path=casino_path,
```